Can you run away from a convex set in a simplex?
Let $C$ be a convex subset of the standard $m$-dimensional simplex $\Delta^m$. Suppose you stand at a point $x\in \Delta^m \setminus C$, and you want to run away from $C$ towards any corner of $\Delta^m$. By "run away" I mean that, while you move, the distance between you and $C$ monotonically increases, like here:

It seems to be always possible, but I could not prove it. Is it always possible?

How do you define the distance between you and $C$? Is it defined as the distance between you and the closest point of $C$?

What do you mean by "some corner"? For certain corners this is obviously not true, for instance, for the top corner on this picture. What does "always" mean? Do you mean all possible starting points? All possible convex subsets? In both cases, the answer is no: consider as the convex subset a line that separates your starting point from the corner, and consider a complex subset that is the whole set (or the whole set minus its boundary).

@FabrizzioMuzz yes

@DaigakunoBaku by "some corner" I meant "there exists a corner that you can run away to". By "always" I mean "for all proper convex subsets, and for all starting points outside the set".

I propose the following reformulation of the problem:
Given an open simplex $\Delta^{m}$ (I would even generalize to any open convex set $X$), embedded into the standard Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^n$ and given any convex proper subset of this set $Y$, is it true that $\forall x \in X\backslash Y$ there exists such continuous path $f(t):[0, 1]\to \bar{X} \backslash Y: f(0)=x, f(1)=C$ from $x$ to at least one corner $C$ of $X$ that along the path the distance from $f(t)$ to $Y$ increases strictly monotonously in $t$.
I believe that the answer is positive; moreover, one of such paths is always an interval of a line. Indeed, consider all straight intervals connecting $x$ with corners $C_{i}$ of the convex set $X$. Suppose on every such interval lies a point $y_{i}$ that belongs to $Y$. Then $Y$, being itself convex, contains the convex hull of all such points. But $x$ obviously belongs to this convex hull, and we supposed that it is not in $Y$ - a contradiction. This is not a strict proof, but I am sure with a bit of work it can be made into one. They key points are to prove that $a):$ $x$ indeed belongs to the convex hull, and $b)$: the interval can be chosen in such a way that the distance from it to $Y$ increases with $t$.

Thanks, your reformulation is correct
